# Dynamic Text Size and System Font in iOS

Tags: ios, textkit

I can't really understand why in the world Apple decided to fix the font family to the system font when using Text Sizes. I saw a couple of tricks here on Stackoverflow that let me change font descriptor programmatically in relation to user preferences but I'm not agree with those solutions. I use Storyboard to define the 90% of the text elements in my application. It doesn't make any sense to manually set all these elements.

That said, my question is: 
**"Is it possible to handle text size from storyboard even using a custom font?"**.
 I'm pretty sure that there is something that I'm missing... it doesn't make any sense that Apple is heavily pushing for this feature and at the same time they ask to use only system font.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? In a storyboard, it is easy to set a custom font and set its size as far as I can tell.

Comment: @MichaelL I'm speaking about Dynamic Text Size of Font Styles. Not the default text size. From the attribute editor in the font panel, select the Font... and as you can see at the end of the list there is a section called "Font Style" these are dynamic font that automatically adapts depending on user preferences. Please read more information here : https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/CustomTextProcessing/CustomTextProcessing.html under "Text styles" paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

After IOS 8 not support for custom font.

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 8.0) {
                    //older than iOS 8 code here

                    [button.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Your Custom Font" size:12]];
                }
                else if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0) {

                    [button.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:nil size:12]];
                }
```

Comment: What does it mean "Not support for custom font" ?This answer is not related to my question anyway :/